# Jcarousel : set CSS transition duration

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jCarousel to make a simple slideshow. It's works fine, I use it really often.
However, I just realised I can't set the transition duration (as I'm using CSS transition).

See the code below :

JS part :

```
var carousel = $('#sliderContainer');
carousel.jcarousel({
     transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions ? {
                transforms: Modernizr.csstransforms,
                transforms3d: Modernizr.csstransforms3d,
                easing: 'ease-in-out',
                // any way to put something like : duration: 1s ?
            } : false
});
```

CSS part (Sass syntax) :

```
#slider
width: 10000%
position: absolute
transition-duration: 5s
-webkit-transition-duration: 5s
```

jCarousel applies the transition on #slider element.

See also the generated HTML :

```
 <div id="slider" style="transition: all 5s ease; -webkit-transition: all 5s ease; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2048px, 0, 0);">
```

The problem here : the transition duration is still on the default (.4 or .5 I guess)...

Any idea ?

Comment: a fiddle would be great

Answer (score 0):

The weird thing was the transition duration here :

```
 <div id="slider" style="transition: all 5s ease; -webkit-transition: all 5s ease; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2048px, 0, 0);">
```

wasn't interpreted.

I simply came over with a !important :

```
#slider
  width: 10000%
  position: absolute
  transition-duration: 5s !important
  -webkit-transition-duration: 5s !important
```

It works. But it's really weird, there was no transition on a parent element, so I don't know why I need a !important...

Answer (score 0):

```
var carousel = $('#sliderContainer');
carousel.jcarousel({
     transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions ? {
                transforms: Modernizr.csstransforms,
                transforms3d: Modernizr.csstransforms3d,
                easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550);',
            } : false
});
```

Ref : http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/